# Standard or best way to structure a GitHub repo for a CommonJS module for use on the front-end with or without build tools or other libraries?

Tags: javascript, github, commonjs

I'm in the process of refactoring a couple of front-end JS snippets I regularly reuse as CommonJS modules. For my own purposes I'll use them with webpack or browserify and so a single JS file that looks like the following would suffice:

```
var Dependency = require('dependency');

function MyModule() {
  // blah blah blah
}

module.exports = MyModule;
```

As long as I've got a package.json in the repo with the required dependencies I'll be able to include this module in future projects via npm/yarn webpack/browserify or whatever my toolset is on that given day.

#### But what if I want the module to be available as a standalone that can be added via a `<script>` tag?

- Should I have 'dist' and 'src' directories in the repo, with the 'dist' directory containing the module code above, alongside an app.js that just says `window.MyModule = require('./mymodule.js');` and the 'dist' directory containing the webpacked output for use with a script tag?
- Should my bundled dist file contain the source of the dependencies or should I note in the readme, that the `<script>` tag for my module should be preceded by `<script>` tags for it's dependencies?
- Instead of a 'dist' directory, should I have an (other) mymodule.js in the repo root alongside an index.html that includes it via a `<script>` tag and demos it's features?

Perhaps I'm over thinking this but I've encountered a number of different strategies in other people's repos, and I'm just wondering if there's any sort of consensus or best practice around this.